# General solution of the Toeplitz' conjecture

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, computational-geometry

> **Toeplitz' conjecture:** *Every continuous simple closed curve in the plane  contains four points that are the vertices of a square.*

I tried to find the general solution for (almost) any curve **f(x,y)=0**.

For instance :

**(-1 + x^2 + y^2)^3 - x^2*y^3 = 0**

```
ContourPlot[(-1 + x^2 + y^2)^3 == x^2*y^3, {x, -1.4, 1.4}, {y, -1.3, 1.5},
Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

There are three **general conditions** to find vertices of a square:

Coordinates of vertices are **(p1,k1),(p2,k2),(p3,k3),(p4,k4)**

Let

```
g[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3 - x^2 y^3
```

1.. *Vertex coordinates satisfy heart equation* g(x,y)=0

```
eq1 = g[p1, k1] == 0;
eq2 = g[p2, k2] == 0;
eq3 = g[p3, k3] == 0;
eq4 = g[p4, k4] == 0;
```

2.. *All sides have equal length.*

```
eq5 = 
  EuclideanDistance[{p1, k1}, {p2, k2}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p2, k2}, {p3, k3}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p3, k3}, {p4, k4}] == 
  EuclideanDistance[{p1, k1}, {p4, k4}];
```

3.. *Every interior angle is a right angle*

```
angle1 = VectorAngle[{p4 - p1, k4 - k1}, {p2 - p1, k2 - k1}] == Pi/2;
angle2 = VectorAngle[{p1 - p2, k1 - k2}, {p3 - p2, k3 - k2}] == Pi/2;
angle3 = VectorAngle[{p4 - p3, k4 - k3}, {p2 - p3, k2 - k3}] == Pi/2;
```

I have  **8 equations** and **8  variables** and I want to find a numerical solutions by using *Mathematica*

I tried :

```
NSolve[eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && angle1 && angle2 && angle3, 
{p1, p2, p3, p4, k1, k2, k3, k4}]
```

or

```
FindRoot[{eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && angle1 && angle2 && angle3}, 
{{p1, 1}, {k1, 1}, {p2, 1}, {k2, 1}, {p3, 1}, {k3,1}, {p4, 1}, {k4, 1}}]
```

But there is no answer ...

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for [mathematica.se].

Answer (score 0):

Once you have chosen two points, the positions of the two others follows.

If you know the curve by parametric equations, two points are obtained from two values of the parameter. Hence you have a system of two equations (expressing that the points are on the curve) in two unknowns.

If you don't have the parametric equations, then it is four equations in four unknowns.